# Lambda pricing limited to account or organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an organization and with in that organization we have 3 accounts.

All 3 accounts have been created month back and the master account of the organization is more than a year old.

I have Lambda function in all 4 account(including the root account).

I know lambda offers 1M free requests per month and 400,000 GB-seconds of compute time per month.

My question here is:

1. Is 1million request per account? or spread through out my organization?
2. Is my organization (root account) still valid for 1M free request? If the request are with in 1million?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/) page says:

- Always Free
- 1,000,000 free requests per month
- Up to 3.2 million seconds of compute time per month

This means that **each account** receives these free limits **every month** (regardless of the age of the account).

Free Tier benefits are not shared *between* accounts. They are given to each account individually.

Comment: if we create 5 different lambda functions in the same account does 1,000,000 free requests per month will be given to each function or it is per account no matter of functions?

Comment: @HamzaMuazzam The first 1m requests to the AWS Lambda service will be free. It is _not_ "per function".

Answer (score 0):

According to this page at Amazon, accounts in an Organization share one set of Free Tier credits. So the Free Tier allocation would be shared among all of the accounts in an Organization.

https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/

**Q8: If we sign-up for Consolidated Billing, can we get the AWS Free Tier for each account?**

No, customers that use Consolidated Billing to consolidate payment across multiple accounts will only have access to one Free Tier per Organization.